# PHP - Increment in Array

Tags: php, arrays, excel, cell, increment

Here, I have an Excel file with three columns containing values, and I want to insert them in a table. So I created my table:

```
$tabl = array(
    $telephone = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' . $i)->getValue(), //La variable telephone prend pour valeur la cellule B
    $y = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C' . $i)->getValue(), //La variable hauteur prend pour valeur la cellule C
    $x = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D' . $i)->getValue() //La variale largeur prend pour valeur la cellule D
);
```

However it only takes me the first cell in the column. So how can I increment my variable $ i?
I tried with $ i ++ but it doesn't work

Comment: is there any loop around?

Comment: no i just have put a loop foreach after :     foreach($tabl as $modele){
        $i++;
      }

Comment: probably you want `$tabl[]`, to loop entire spreadsheet and to add `$i` into that.

Comment: Where did you try to increment that variable in your code? Please share all attempts

Comment: @NicoHaase I created another question that describes my problem more generally stackoverflow.com/questions/60095963/sort-page-by-images-name

Answer (score 2):

```
$highestRow = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();     
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row)
{
    $tabl = array(
        $telephone = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' . $row)->getValue(), //La variable telephone prend pour valeur la cellule B
        $y = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C' . $row)->getValue(), //La variable hauteur prend pour valeur la cellule C
        $x = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D' . $row)->getValue() //La variale largeur prend pour valeur la cellule D  
    );
    //TO DO: Perform SQL Insertion
}
```

Comment: I created another question that describes my problem more generally stackoverflow.com/questions/60095963/sort-page-by-images-name